# Difference between ContextLoaderListener and RequestContextListener?

Tags: java, spring

I have googled it but not found satisfactory answer, it would be great if you guys can explain the difference between `ContextLoaderListener` and `RequestContextListener`.

Answer (score 16):

**[contextloaderlistener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html) :-** Bootstrap listener to start up Spring's root WebApplicationContext. Simply delegates to ContextLoader.

**[requestcontextlistener :-](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html)** This listener is mainly for use with third-party servlets, e.g. the JSF FacesServlet. Within Spring's own web support, DispatcherServlet's processing is perfectly sufficient.

Comment: Can you explain which one is better to use? and why?

Answer (score 5):

If you use a Servlet 2.5 web container, with requests processed outside of
Spring’s DispatcherServlet (for example, when using JSF or Struts), you need
to register the **org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener**
ServletRequestListener. For Servlet 3.0+, this can be done programmatically via the
WebApplicationInitializer interface. Alternatively, or for older containers, add the following
declaration to your web application’s web.xml file:

> ```
>     <listener>
>         <listener-class>
>             org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
>         </listener-class>
>     </listener>
>
> </web-app>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I have read that If you use the ContextLoaderListener you don't need the RequestContextListener or Filter. It registers the current request(attributes) in a thread local so that the scoped proxies can use it.

Comment: Just in case - I wasn't able to make request-scope beans working without adding RequestContextListener with WebApplicationInitializer-based approach of Spring initialization

Answer (score 0):

ContextLoaderListener is a bootstrap listener to startup Spring's root WebApplicationContext.

RequestContextListener is used when you want the attributes in your request thread to stay alive.

The point to be noted here is that, the inheritable flag is set to false in the RequestContextListener.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html

So If you want that a child thread inherits the request attributes then you should try using RequestContextFilter or RequestContextHolder.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html